# Division_Euclidean_space.h error: ‘vertex_t’ is not a type

Tags: c++, boost

I have this class, but I am getting an error only in the BOOST case.

```
template<typename T>
class Division_Euclidean_space {
 public:
  typedef T FT;

#ifdef RKD_WITH_BOOST
 struct Vertex{ std::vector<FT> v;};
 typedef struct Vertex Vertex;

 typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::listS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS, Vertex > Graph;
 typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
#endif

#ifdef RKD_WITH_BOOST
  void insert(Graph& g, vertex_t& v) {
        for(int i = 0; i < g[v].v.size(); ++i)
            p.push_back(g[v].v[i]);
  }
#endif
...
```

I am actually getting many errors, but I believe that if I fix this, I will be fine then

```
Division_Euclidean_space.h:102:25: error: ‘vertex_t’ is not a type
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;` declares a variable.

You probably meant:

```
typedef typename boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
```

Comment: Jarod, I think that's solves the issue! I found this statement: "typedef is to declare a type, typename is used to get the type which templates" on my way on understanding `typename`! DO you agree with it or you have something "better"?

Comment: I agree with it with a little modification: `typedef` is to declare a *alias* type. Both are equals, it is not an extra type. I mean `std::is_same<type1, type2>::value` is true for `typedef type1 type2;`.

Comment: Thanks Jarod. I got a -1 and I can't delete the question because it is answered now. What should I do?

Comment: @G.Samaras _"I got a -1 and I can't delete the question because it is answered now. What should I do?"_ Ask on [Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) about such concerns.

Comment: Will do @πάνταῥεῖ. Didn't understand it was such a bad question, so I would like to remove it since it doesn't help the others. Here is the question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281105/i-got-a-1-and-i-cant-delete-the-question-because-it-is-answered-now-what-shou

Comment: @G. Samaras - it was not *"such a bad question"*. You got caught up in the community mishandling a question and its rough-handling a user. For example, there was no reason for anyone to cast a ***why isn't this code working*** close vote since you provided that with the question. Stack Overflow has a few well known problems that some people don't like to talk about. Artifacts are sprayed all over the web. See, for example http://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow+jerk and https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow+sucks. I hope that answers the questions you raised in the comments.

Comment: Thanks @jww and everyone for the help and the tips. :) Merry Christmas :)